# querySelectorAll doesn't capture all elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to scan and manipulate DOM of a webpage the following Code:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('*');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
   if (!elements[i].firstElementChild) { 
       if (elements[i].innerHTML != "" ){ 
           elements[i].innerHTML = "abc_"+ elements[i].innerHTML+"_123";
       }
   }
}
```

While it works well on many pages, it is not picking up all the elements on a specific page that is my real target. On that page, it captures and edit strings of few elements, but not all.
I have also tried using getElementsByTagName()

The elements that are not captured have an XPath such as:

```
/html/body/div[4]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/nav/div/div[1]/div/span/div/text()[1]
```

I also noticed "flex" written in front of these elements.

I also tried the script by Douglas Crockford, but, this also is unable to catch the elements described above.

The script by Douglas is published at

https://www.javascriptcookbook.com/article/traversing-dom-subtrees-with-a-recursive-walk-the-dom-function/

```
function walkTheDOM(node, func) {
    func(node);
    node = node.firstChild;
    while (node) {
        walkTheDOM(node, func);
        node = node.nextSibling;
    }
}

// Example usage: Process all Text nodes on the page
walkTheDOM(document.body, function (node) {
    if (node.nodeType === 3) { // Is it a Text node?
        var text = node.data.trim();
        if (text.length > 0) { // Does it have non white-space text content?
            // process text
        }
    }
});
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Here is a screenshot of inspect element:
[[image]]

Comment: And this final div doesn't have a child element? Any chance we can see such an example by ourselves?

Comment: I edited the question to put the entire XPATH of the text element under the last div. Since the application is proprietory, I am not allowed to share the actual application.

Comment: The "flex" badge there is just the browser telling you visually, that the element is using flexbox.

Comment: So you are targeting the <div> that's below the "All" TextNode? This element is empty, so its innerHTML is `""`, you specifically avoid such elements: `if (elements[i].innerHTML != "" ){`

Comment: If I remove the line that checks if the element is empty or not, a lot of hidden divs also get modified and the page looks ugly. Also, it still doesn't catch the targeted elements.

Comment: @F.Müller, thanks for explaining this. What I have observed is the elements added under flexbox are not being captured by my script.

Comment: When does your script run? Are the missing elements inserted into the DOM dynamically?

Comment: Please try to create a minimal reproducer.

Comment: I have created a plugin and this is a complete code that I am running in a content_script.

Comment: @Lennholm Yes, the missing elements are inserted into the DOM dynamically. The script runs at the end of document loading.

Comment: @RyotaKaneko Dynamically as in following the response of an AJAX request or something else that is asynchronous? The symptoms to me suggest that the elements haven't been inserted yet at the time your script runs.

Comment: @RyotaKaneko Please provide an example that we can reproduce. If we cannot reproduce it, we cannot help you, really. Also, on StackOverflow please do not post images of code. It is bad for search-engines, we cannot copy the code or run it and on top of it, the image may get deleted as well. The tree-walking code works as expected. Please create a snippet somewhere with the setup that does not work. Also make sure the elements are really all there when you run the code.

Comment: @RyotaKaneko Besides, the standalone text-nodes won't be modified because you exclude them with .firstElementChild.

Comment: You need a different rule then. If you don't want to target other empty elements but this one, you must define how "this one" is different.

Comment: Lennholm and Kaiido Thanks, the questions and pointers helped me dig into this further. The script runs fine when I associate with events such as clock, DoubleClick, etc. Since the data is dynamically loaded, the elements that contain dynamically loaded data don't get processed.

Answer (score 1):

In your snippet, you are not selecting all the nodes, since `document.querySelectorAll(*)` does not select the text-nodes, but only elements.

Besides, you are explicitly ignoring the text-nodes, because you specify `.firstElementChild`. A text-node is not an element. An element in the DOM is a "tag" like `<div>` for example. It has the `nodeType: 1` a text-node has `nodeType: 3`.

So, if you'd process for example:

```html
OuterTextNode<div>InnerTextNode</div>
```

the `div` would be the first element and Inner- and OuterTextNode are text-nodes. Both, the query selector and the `.firstElementChild` would only select the element (div) here.

It should work with the DOM-tree-walking code:

```js
const blackList = ['script']; // here you could add some node names that you want to ignore

function walkTheDOM(node, func) {
  func(node);
  node = node.firstChild;
  while (node) {
    if (!blackList.includes(node.nodeName.toLowerCase())) {
      walkTheDOM(node, func);
    }
    node = node.nextSibling;
  }
}

walkTheDOM(document.body, function(node) {
  if (node.nodeType === 3) {
    var text = node.data.trim();
    if (text.length > 0) {
      console.log(text);
      console.log(`replaced: PREFIX_${text}_POSTFIX`);
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  top: 0;
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<div>
  All
  <span>In span</span> Some more text
  <div>
    <div>
      Some nested text
      <div>Sibling</div>
      <span>
      Another
      Another
      <span>
        Deep
        <span>
          <span>
            <span>
              <span>
                <span>Deeper</span>
      </span>
      </span>
      </span>
      </span>
      </span>
      </span>
    </div>
    <!-- Some comment !-->
    <script>
      // some script
      const foo = 'foo';
    </script>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: They don't exclude text nodes, they never included it, querySelectorAll("*") targets only elements.

Comment: @Kaiido You are right. I did not point that out. Will add this part, too.

Comment: @F.Müller, Thanks. The code that you provided works.